# carry Data from a TRY While Loop? 

Tags: c#, while-loop

Consider this `while` loop that keeps nulling my values once it has finished.

The `counterm` string is now null at the end of the program. How can we carry the value from the while loop?

```
void somefunction() {   
    try {                  
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("Counter.txt"))
      {
        String line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            string countern = line + "_1";
            string counterm = line + "_2";
            int counter = Convert.ToInt32(line);
            sr.test(counterm);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Let the user know what went wrong.
    Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Thread.Sleep(60000);            
    }
}
public static void test(counterm)
{
        Console.WriteLine(counterm);
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: yeah if counterm is defined outside the while loop, then you shouldn't have "string " in front of it inside. (i think someone else mentioned this below, just bringing it up top...)

Comment: I dont get what `sr.test();` is. Is your class called `sr` as well as the StreamReader instance?

Comment: hi you can ignor the sr.test i wast trying something else out there iv removed the starting string replaced the everything mentoned but still not working heres the entire code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`counterm` is a variable local to your loop. Also your code does not compile because it's incomplete but my suggestion would be something like this:

```
string ParseCounters()
{
    string counterm = "";

    ...
    String line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        ...
        counterm = line + "_2"
    }
    ...

    return counterm;

}

public static void test()
{
    Console.WriteLine(ParseCounter());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `counterm` is only in scope within the while loop.

Declare your variables in a higher scope to have access to them from outside the while loop.

Comment: He's actually trying to access them in a separate method all together apparently.

Comment: there defined in a higher scoop and it compiles but when you run through it line by line it just revers the values back to null so wont show in the test method

Answer (score 1):

The scope of your variables is **within the while-loop only**. Outside the loop are not defined. This shouldn't even compile unless you have also declared your variables in global scope.

---

From comment:
Then your while-loop should probably look like this:

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    countern = line + "_1";
    counterm = line + "_2";
    int counter = Convert.ToInt32(line);

    sr.test();    // why `sr`? there is no test-method defined for streamreader.
                  // is your class called `sr` as well?
}
```

Variables only "live" within the scope they are defined in. Opon redefining the variables you are actually creating new variables, not writing to the global ones.

Comment: yer there decliaed higher up 

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        string countern="", counterm="";
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              try
        {

Comment: @Ben: updated the answer. Note that you should not call sr.test() but just test().

Comment: @Ben Wilson i think you're missing something; in your loop you have `string countern = line + "_1";` and `string counterm = line + "_2";` but assuming countern and counterm are defined elsewhere, you need to drop the `string`; like in the code from Avada Kedavra's example above.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're declaring the variable inside the while block, the variable gets removed as soon as you exit that block. You'd have to declare it farther up.

Is this your entire program? What you have listed there doesn't look like it would compile because counterm isn't declared at all inside the test() method.

Comment: no this is just a side little bit i have but together to try and get this thing to work first